# How to get text from specific url?

Tags: python, api

I was wondering if there's any way to get text from certain url using python.

For example, from this one https://www.ixbt.com/news/2022/04/20/160-radeon-rx-6400.html

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out beautifulsoup4.

Comment: Lots of options. There are tools such as `requests` that post urls and get responses. There is `selenium` that runs a web browser to get the data. There are a million examples on the net, so start with an internet search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do web scraping in python using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ixbt.com/news/2022/04/20/160-radeon-rx-6400.html"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

text = soup.get_text()
```

After that you could save the extracted text into a text file:

```
text_file = open("webscrap.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
text_file.write(text)
text_file.close()
```